# Python achieve VID and PID

Tags: python, usb

In my program I need every time a USB device is connected to print this:
DEVICE NAME | PID | VID

I'de made a little research but I got so confused.
I'm interested to build this in Python, though, if it's easier in other languages,
i'de like to see how.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I recommend you to check [pyusb](http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html) and maybe this post will help you too [python usb detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570548/python-usb-detection)

Comment: What OS do you use? On Linux it may be easier to start a Python script from a udev rule. Or use pyudev as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109879/usb-devices-udev-and-d-bus).

Comment: The OS i'll use it going to be probably Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
    
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
    
        fileMenu = Menu(menu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New Window")
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Close window", command=self.exitProgram)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

        editMenu = Menu(menu)
        editMenu.add_command(label="Undo")
        editMenu.add_command(label="Redo")
        editMenu.add_separator()
        editMenu.add_command(label="Cut")
        editMenu.add_command(label="Copy")
        editMenu.add_command(label="Paste")
        editMenu.add_command(label="Delete")
        editMenu.add_separator()
        editMenu.add_command(label="Select All")
        editMenu.add_separator()
        editMenu.add_command(label="New Connection")
        editMenu.add_command(label="Send Payload")
        editMenu.add_command(label="Search")
        menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)

        viewMenu = Menu(menu)
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Reload")
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Force Reload")
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Toggle Developer Tools")
        viewMenu.add_separator()
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Actual Size")
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Zoom In")
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Zoom Out")
        viewMenu.add_separator()
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Toggle Full Screen", command=self.exitProgram)
        menu.add_cascade(label="View", menu=viewMenu)

        windowMenu = Menu(menu)
        windowMenu.add_command(label="Minimize")
        windowMenu.add_command(label="Zoom")
        windowMenu.add_command(label="Close Window", command=self.exitProgram)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Window", menu=windowMenu)

        helpMenu = Menu(menu)
        helpMenu.add_command(label="Learn More About MQTTX")
        helpMenu.add_command(label="Learn More About EMQX")
        helpMenu.add_command(label="Report Problem")
        helpMenu.add_separator()
        helpMenu.add_command(label="MQTTX Website")
        helpMenu.add_command(label="EMQX Website", command=self.exitProgram)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu)

        
        options_frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#c3c3c3')
        O_btn = tk.Button(options_frame1, text='O', font=('Bold',15), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
        O_btn.place(x=35, y=50)
        plus_btn = tk.Button(options_frame1, text='+', font=('Bold',15), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
        plus_btn.place(x=35, y=125)
        gl_btn = tk.Button(options_frame1, text='</>', font=('Bold',10), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
        gl_btn.place(x=32.5, y=200)
        l_btn = tk.Button(options_frame1, text='#', font=('Bold',15), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
        l_btn.place(x=35, y=275)
        S_btn = tk.Button(options_frame1, text='*', font=('Bold',15), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
        S_btn.place(x=35, y=375)
        eam_btn = tk.Button(options_frame1, text='<->', font=('Bold',10), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
        eam_btn.place(x=32.5, y=450)
        a_btn = tk.Button(options_frame1, text='@', font=('Bold',10), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
        a_btn.place(x=37, y=525)
        options_frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        options_frame1.pack_propagate(False)
        options_frame1.configure(width=100, height=600)

        options_frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
        L1 = Label(options_frame2, text = 'Device Name',font = 50)
        L1.pack()
        backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda x: "./libusb/x64/libusb-1.0.dll")
        devices = usb.core.find(..., backend=backend)
        devices = usb.core.find(find_all=TRUE)
        device = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1234, idProduct=0x5678)
        cb1 = ttk.Combobox(options_frame2)
        for device in devices: 
           cb1['values']=("VID: {:04x}, PID: {:04x}".format(device.idVendor, device.idProduct))
        '''cb1=Combobox(options_frame2,
                 values=["VID: {:04x}, PID: {:04x}".format(device.idVendor, device.idProduct)],
                 font=('Arial Black', 20),state="readonly")'''
        cb1.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        B1 = Button(options_frame2, text='connect', font=40)
        B1.pack(padx=7,pady=7 )
        options_frame2.pack(fill=BOTH)
        options_frame2.pack_propagate(True)
        options_frame2.configure(width=1100, height=600)
        

        main_frame = tk.Frame(root)


        main_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        main_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        main_frame.configure(height=600, width=1100)
        root.geometry('1200x600')
            
           
        
    def exitProgram(self):
        exit()
    
        
root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root . title("MQTTX")
root . resizable(True, True)
root . mainloop()
```

Comment: It is my own program. It will work. It's used to display your system or lap one port's VID and PID in combo box

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think this answer would be better if the code was more concise. Do  you really need to implement cut, copy, paste, zooming in and out,  and some of the other functions just to show a piece of information?